# Apache PDFBox unable to render german umlauts characters while converting Pdf to Image

Tags: java, pdfbox

We are using apache PDFBox opensource library to convert PDF to Image but it's failing to render German Umlauts – ä, ö, ü characters when the pdf is converted as Image file on the Linux servers. Works well from windows based machines but not working properly from a linux based machine. This looks to be due to the missing fonts on the Linux machine. Is there a way to ship the font library along with our application (war file) and use the font library from the classpath and make it available for PDFBox? If this isn't right approach pls suggest any alternative(s)

Thanks,
[PDF to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIaAs.png)

Comment: Just a side remark, not only German umlauts are drawn incorrectly, also other accented characters, e.g. ó and ú.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What version of PDFBox are you using? Hopefully 2.0.26. PDFBox includes a fallback font so this shouldn't happen. Additional fonts can be put in the .fonts directory in your home directory. (And of course at the place where your OS keeps fonts)

Comment: Hi @tilman-hausherr, we are using version 2.0.25, upgraded to 3.0.0-RC1 to test in lower environment, still no luck.

Comment: Do you get any log output? If your application doesn't allow logs, try PDFDebugger.

Comment: here's a snippet from the logs, it falls back on 'LiberationSans' for all the missing fonts: 
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Roman
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Bold

Comment: Yeah that's what I expected. In theory it should work, although it wouldn't look very good. Try installing the microsoft fonts with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Comment: Yea font installation worked with the underlying implementation, is there a way we can pass fonts programmatically ?

Comment: Put then programmatically in the .fonts directory of your user directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with parsing special symbols as well. However, in my case I believe it had nothing to do with fonts, but rather with encoding.

Try using different encodings when setting COSSString, for me **ISO_8859** worked:

```
    COSString cossString = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
    String string = cossString.getString();
    // Do some string manipulations here
    // ...
    cossString.setValue(string.getBytes(Charsets.ISO_8859_1.name()));
```

I am using PDFBox 2.0.28:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
       <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.28</version>
    </dependency>
```